# Pull git submodules after cloning project from GitHub

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project that has specified submodules in it. Everything works well on the dev machine. I have commited `.gitmodules` file and pulled on the production. However it does not pulled submodules.

If I go into submodule directories and call `git pull`, nothing happens.

What is the proper way to pull those submodules in the new project ?

Answer (score 411, accepted):

From the root of the repo just run:

```
git submodule update --init
```

Comment: I believe this will actually update your dependencies. I think S. Russel had the right command in his comment below:
`git pull --recurse-submodules`

Comment: @Spencer  command `git submodule update --init`  works fine in git version 2.31.1; it cloned all submodules.

Comment: @Spencer for me `git submodule update --init` worked and `git pull --recurse-submodules` did not.

Comment: @Spencer those two commands are not equivalent as `git pull --recurse-submodules` will not clone the dependencies but only pull new commits, cf `git pull --help`: « *Using --recurse-submodules can only fetch new commits in already checked out submodules right now* ».
Hence, to « pull » the dependencies (eg if `--recurse-submodules` was forgotten when cloning) you will have to use `git submodule update --init --recursive` (the `--recursive` to also clone/pull nested submodules as shown by @Iglesk)

Answer (score 114):

If there are nested submodules, you will need to use:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Comment: Think that's the most complete and compact answer! Any known drawback?

Answer (score 89):

If you need to pull stuff for submodules into your submodule repositories use

```
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

But this will not checkout proper commits(the ones your master repository points to) in submodules

To checkout proper commits in your submodules you should update them after pulling using

```
git submodule update --recursive
```

Comment: `git submodule update --recursive` is what I needed after first `git clone`ing but forgetting to `--recursive` on the first go. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. The submodules remain empty.

Comment: @CodeMonkey same to me.

Comment: might be too late to the party but for anyone ended up here: 
```git submodule update --init --recursive``` solve my issue

Comment: Just `git submodule update --init` did it for me - no `--recursive` necessary.

Answer (score 16):

I just want to share these.

First way,

```
git submodule init && git submodule update
```

The below is just basically combining the first way,

```
git submodule update --init
```

If there are any nested submodules, [Iglesk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57920691/15393232) is the way to go.