# .NET Web API, Submodules project not loading on cloning

Tags: c#, git, bitbucket, .net-5

I have .NET 5 WEB API project that is consuming services from the submodules. These submodules have its own repository.

I am using *GitBlash* and *BitBucket* as repository.

I have added submodule reference by:

```
 git submodule add http://bitbucket.org/myprojectA
```

then I went in Visual Studio, opened the project and created folder 'Submodule', followed by I add project references of submodule within the project folder. I commit and push changes.

Then I cloned the same project from BitBucket using *SourceTree* to test, I opened API project in visual studio and I got the warning message

```
 one or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly
```

Not sure what I am missing. Do I need to run some git bash command to update reference??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pull git submodules after cloning project from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773642/pull-git-submodules-after-cloning-project-from-github)

Comment: not it did not solve the problem.. I have tried both Git command to update submodule

Comment: I do receive submodule folder only but not code

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

## 1. Explicit get submodules

```sh
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

## 2. Clone with submodules

```sh
git clone --recursive <repo URL>
```