# ERROR: Could not build wheels for ndi-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, pip, ndi

I am trying to install ndi-python package in my mac, I am getting the below error, anyone got idea on how to fix this issue.

```
 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:10 (add_subdirectory):
        add_subdirectory given source "lib/pybind11" which is not an existing
        directory.
      
      
      -- Found NDI: /Library/NDI SDK for Apple
      CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:19 (pybind11_add_module):
        Unknown CMake command "pybind11_add_module".
      
      
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      error: command '/opt/homebrew/bin/cmake' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for ndi-python
  Running setup.py clean for ndi-python
Failed to build ndi-python
**ERROR: Could not build wheels for ndi-python, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects**
```

[Console Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XCQB.png)

Scenario I am working on: Listing all the ndi sources available

I tried installing `ndi-python`

command used: pip install ndi-python
Python version: 3.9
IDE used: PyCharm

Comment: The directory `lib/pybind11` corresponds to a **git submodule**: https://github.com/buresu/ndi-python/tree/master/lib. Make sure that your clone the project with submodules.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the first part of your error message, which says:

> add_subdirectory given source "lib/pybind11" which is not an existing directory.

As [Tsyvarev stated](/q/76154220/#comment134300520_76154220), this is a git submodule. See https://github.com/buresu/ndi-python/tree/master/lib. It sounds like you did a clone without passing [the `--recurse-submodules` flag](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---recurse-submodulesltpathspecgt). You can fix this though, by running [`git submodule update --init`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203) (See also [Pull git submodules after cloning project from GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16773642/11107541)).